# How to implement a 'WHERE EXISTS' clause in SQL SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, join, select, where-clause, exists

I need to make sure that the query listed below is implemented as a nested query with EXISTS/NOT EXISTS clauses.

"Find the first and last name of drivers who performed at least one trip in 2017."

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.FNAME, EMPLOYEE.LNAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT ENUM FROM DRIVER WHERE EMPLOYEE.ENUM=DRIVER.ENUM) AND 
(SELECT LNUM FROM TRIP WHERE TRIP.LNUM=DRIVER.LNUM AND 
YEAR(TDATE)=2017);
```

I am not sure whether or not it is a syntax error or whether I have entered the wrong values. However, I triple checked all the values and they seem to match the table data.

Below I have listed the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TRIP(
TNUM        DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
LNUM        DECIMAL(8)  NOT NULL,
REGNUM      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
TDATE       DATE    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT TRIP_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (TNUM),
CONSTRAINT TRIP_CKEY UNIQUE (LNUM, REGNUM, TDATE),
CONSTRAINT TRIP_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (LNUM) REFERENCES DRIVER(LNUM),
CONSTRAINT TRIP_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY (REGNUM) REFERENCES TRUCK(REGNUM) );

CREATE TABLE DRIVER(
ENUM        DECIMAL(12) NOT NULL,
LNUM        DECIMAL(8)  NOT NULL,
STATUS      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT DRIVER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(ENUM),
CONSTRAINT DRIVER_UNIQUE UNIQUE(LNUM),
CONSTRAINT DRIVER_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(ENUM) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ENUM),
CONSTRAINT DRIVER_STATUS CHECK ( STATUS IN ('AVAILABLE', 'BUSY', 'ON 
LEAVE')) );

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
ENUM        DECIMAL(12) NOT NULL,
FNAME       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
INITIALS    VARCHAR(5)      NULL,
LNAME       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DOB         DATE            NULL,
BLDG        DECIMAL(3)  NOT NULL,
STREET      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SUBURB      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
STATE       VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
ZIPCODE     DECIMAL(4)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(ENUM) );
```

Below I have listed the table data:

```
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 1, 10001, 'PKR768', '2015-01-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 2, 10001, 'SYF777', '2015-02-20' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 3, 10001, 'KKK007', '2015-03-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 4, 10001, 'PKR768', '2015-06-29' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 5, 20002, 'PKR768', '2015-01-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 6, 10002, 'SYF777', '2015-02-20' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 7, 30005, 'KKK007', '2015-03-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 8, 10001, 'PKR768', '2015-01-13' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 9, 10002, 'QRT834', '2015-09-17' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(10, 30005, 'KKK007', '2015-12-15' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(11, 10003, 'SST005', '2016-01-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(12, 10002, 'PKR768', '2016-03-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(13, 20002, 'QRT834', '2015-04-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(14, 20002, 'PKR008', '2015-04-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(15, 30005, 'PKR768', '2015-05-24' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(16, 30005, 'SST005', '2014-08-02' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(17, 20002, 'QRT834', '2014-09-17' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(18, 10001, 'KKK007', '2014-12-15' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(19, 30005, 'SST005', '2016-01-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(20, 10003, 'PKR768', '2016-03-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(21, 10001, 'QRT834', '2012-04-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(22, 30005, 'PKR008', '2012-04-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(23, 10003, 'PKR768', '2012-05-25' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(24, 20002, 'SST005', '2012-08-02' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(25, 10001, 'PKR768', '2014-01-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(26, 10001, 'SYF777', '2013-02-20' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(27, 20002, 'KKK007', '2013-03-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(28, 30005, 'PKR768', '2010-06-29' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(29, 10001, 'QRT834', '2010-09-17' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(30, 10002, 'KKK007', '2010-12-15' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(31, 10003, 'SST005', '2010-01-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(32, 20002, 'PKR768', '2010-03-12' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(33, 30005, 'QRT834', '2003-04-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(34, 30005, 'PKR008', '2004-04-23' );
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES(35, 10001, 'PKR768', '2017-05-24' );

INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 1, 10001, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 2, 10008, 'ON LEAVE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 3, 10002, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 4, 10004, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 5, 10003, 'ON LEAVE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 6, 10012, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 7, 20002, 'BUSY' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 8, 20003, 'BUSY' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 9, 30005, 'BUSY' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 10, 40002, 'BUSY' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 11, 20045, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 12, 20055, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 13, 20065, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 14, 10305, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 15, 10345, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 16, 10705, 'AVAILABLE' );
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES( 17, 40005, 'AVAILABLE' );

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 1, 'John', NULL, 'Smith', NULL, 42, 
'Victoria St.', 'Hurstville', 'NSW', 2456 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 2, 'Peter', NULL, 'Taylor', '1970-01- 
12', 42, 'Victoria St.', 'Hurstville', 'NSW', 2456 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 3, 'John', NULL, 'Doe', '1966-03-23', 
12, 'Station St.', 'Dapto', 'NSW', 2530 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 4, 'John', NULL, 'Gray', '1988-05-05', 
16, 'Station St.', 'Dapto', 'NSW', 2530 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 5, 'Adam', NULL, 'Taylor', '1980-01-01', 
42, 'Church St.', 'City', 'NSW', 2300 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 6, 'Michael', NULL, 'Jones', '1975-03- 
05', 23, 'Waterloo Ave.', 'Surry Hills', 'NSW', 2502 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 7, 'Frederic', NULL, 'Jones', NULL, 3, 
'Victoria St.', 'Redfern', 'NSW', 2420 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 8, 'Peter', NULL, 'O''Brien', '1983-02- 
28', 19, 'Lucas Dr.', 'Horsley', 'NSW', 2530 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 9, 'John', NULL, 'Lucas', '1966-12-16', 
20, 'Huxley St.', 'Horsley', 'NSW', 2530 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 10, 'John', NULL, 'Fox', '1975-10-15', 
18, 'Victoria St.', 'Hurstville', 'NSW', 2456 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 11, 'Adam', NULL, 'Fox', NULL, 45, 
'Victoria St.', 'Hurstville', 'NSW', 2456 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 12, 'Phillip', NULL, ',Cox', '1984-12- 
12', 5, 'The Avenue', 'Rockdale', 'NSW', 2300 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 13, 'Andrew', 'K', 'Smith', '1969-04- 
04', 42, 'Bambaramba Ave.', 'Pennant Hills', 'NSW', 2556 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 14, 'Andrew', 'R', 'Smith', '1992-04- 
01', 67, 'King Cr.', 'Hurstville', 'NSW', 2456 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 15, 'Michael', NULL, 'Potter', '1995-04- 
01', 568, 'Bong Bong St.', 'Horsley', 'NSW', 2530 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 16, 'Harry', NULL, 'Potter', '1995-04- 
01', 568, 'Bong Bong St.', 'Horsley', 'NSW', 2530 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 17, 'James', NULL, 'Bond', NULL, 007, 
'Alan Bond St.', 'Perth', 'WA', 6000 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 18, 'Paris', NULL, 'Hilton', NULL, 1, 
'Hilton St.', 'Melbourne', 'Vic', 3000 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 19, 'Lady', NULL, 'Gaga', NULL, 3, 'Pork 
st.', 'Hobart', 'Tas', 7000 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES( 20, 'Robin', NULL, 'Hood', NULL, 6, 
'Nottingham Pl.', 'Sydney', 'NSW', 2000 );
```

Comment: Rather than two queries in your EXISTS, I suggest you try a single query - join DRIVER and TRIP

Comment: Seems like your homework continued? where exists (something) and exists (something else)

Comment: Please include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok i just did then @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT E.FNAME, E.LNAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM DRIVER D
              WHERE D.ENUM = E.ENUM
             ) AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TRIP T
              WHERE T.LNUM = E.LNUM AND YEAR(T.TDATE) = 2017
             );
```

You need to repeat the `EXISTS`.  In addition:

- Use table aliases and qualify *all* column references.  This is a best practice, so get used to it now when you are learning SQL.
- The value in the `SELECT` for an `EXISTS` is irrelevant.  I use `1` because it is easy to type.
- Not all databases support `YEAR()`.  The standard syntax is `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.TDATE)`.  I assume your database does support the function you are using.
- I doubt that you really need to compare to `DRIVERS` (in the real world).  Wouldn't a drive on a trip automatically be a "driver"?

Comment: This helped, however I keep getting a syntax error stating: SQL Error: Unknown column 'D.LNUM' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Noods . . . There is no `D.LNUM` in this query.  Obviously, the correlation clauses need to refer to columns in the corresponding tables.